# Cannot open properties window and cannot attach database SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

This is the scenario of the network. The main server/instance is using SQL 2012, and I want to connect to database using SQL 2008.I can login, run a query but the problem is I cannot open any dialog/window like properties and attach database.

This is the error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Cannot show requested dialog.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)

---

Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.DefaultLaunchFormHostedControlAllocator.AllocateDialog(XmlDocument initializationXml, IServiceProvider dialogServiceProvider, CDataContainer dc)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.DefaultLaunchFormHostedControlAllocator.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ILaunchFormHostedControlAllocator.CreateDialog(XmlDocument initializationXml, IServiceProvider dialogServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.LaunchForm.InitializeForm(XmlDocument doc, IServiceProvider provider, ISqlControlCollection control)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.LaunchForm..ctor(XmlDocument doc, IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ToolMenuItemHelper.OnCreateAndShowForm(IServiceProvider sp, XmlDocument doc)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.RunningFormsTable.RunningFormsTableImpl.ThreadStarter.StartThread()

===================================

Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlPropertyMetadataProvider.PropertyNameToIDLookupWithException(String propertyName, PropertyAccessPurpose pap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbComparer(Boolean inServer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitializeStringComparer()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AbstractCollectionBase.get_StringComparer()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectCollectionBase.InitInnerCollection()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.get_InternalStorage()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.GetObjectByKey(ObjectKeyBase key)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginCollection.get_Item(String name)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateLogin..ctor(CDataContainer context)

Hoping for your help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. You can connect from SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to instance of SQL Server 2012 but your options will be very limited - basically to writing queries. You can't use most of SSMS features.

You have two options here:

A - Attach the database using query. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx) and example:

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'DatabaseName', 
    @filename1 = N'D:\SQL\Data\DatabaseName.mdf', 
    @filename2 = N'E:\SQL\Log\DatabaseName.ldf';
```

B - Install SQL Server Management Studio 2012. Express edition is available for free, and you don't need to install the database engine, you can just install the SSMS.

**EDIT:** There might be a third option. I can not guarantee, but applying latest SP and updates to your 2008, might make it work with 2012 instance with full features.

Still, I would recommend installing SSMS 2012 to work with. It works fine with older instances.